# setViewBox() in Raphael?

Tags: javascript, raphael

[Fiddle!!](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/DCxdY/8/)

I have set this fiddle up to show what parameters are going into the setViewBox() function. The thing is, the way it is working makes no sense to me.

Why does `setViewBox(0, 0, 625, 625)` result in a larger box / further zoomed in than `setViewBox(0, 0, 1250, 1250)`?

Also, why does `setViewBox(-100, 0, 625, 625);` adjust the image to the right (I would expect it to go left because of the negative x value)?

This is what the docs say about setViewBox(x, y, w, h):

parameters:

x - new x position, default is 0

y - new y position, default is 0

w - new width of the canvas

h - new height of the canvas

Also, I am trying to figure out the relationship between the first(x) / third(w) and the second(y) / fourth(h) parameters such that the box zooms in and out from the middle, instead of expanding from the top left corner, if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: Updating view box rescales canvas wrt original dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that the parameters passed to setViewBox  are basically telling the size of the window you're looking through at the object. If the window is smaller, you see less of the object, or the object zoomed in. If you move the window left, you'll see the object move right, relative to the window. The key is to think of it as a window you're looking through, not the size of the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example showing how to calculate the setViewBox values, you have to include jquery (to get SVG cocntainer X and Y ) :

```
var original_width = 777;
var original_height = 667;
var zoom_width = map_width*100/original_width/100;
var zoom_height = map_height*100/original_height/100;
if(zoom_width<=zoom_height)
   zoom = zoom_width;
else
   zoom = zoom_height;
rsr.setViewBox($("#"+map_name).offset().left, $("#"+map_name).offset().top, (map_width/zoom), (map_height/zoom));
```

Comment: I think you can check @abdelali-ahbib 's origin post for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774019/raphael-js-setviewbox-didnt-resize-my-paper