# raphael js setViewBox didn't resize my paper

Tags: javascript, html, raphael

I have a problem with setViewBox on raphael, The paper isn't resized even if I did `myPaper.setViewBox(0, 0, new_map_width, new_map_height,true);` (Line 9 on the JS code)

Nb : new_map_width = 400 and new_map_height=300 and the map is at 800*600

this is my code : http://jsfiddle.net/xperali/zdbzJ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I have to execute my setViewBox method after drawing all the paths, and use some math skills :)

```
var original_width = 777;
var original_height = 667;
var zoom_width = map_width/original_width;
var zoom_height = map_height/original_height;
if(zoom_width<=zoom_height)
   zoom = zoom_width;
else
   zoom = zoom_height;
rsr.setViewBox($("#"+map_name).offset().left, $("#"+map_name).offset().top, (map_width/zoom), (map_height/zoom));
```

Comment: (map_width*100/original_width/100) is the same as (map_width / original_width)